# Uppercase, lowercase and other counter

Tags: java

So I've been making a small piece of code in Java that takes input from the user counts the uppercase, lowercase and other parts (such as spaces, numbers, even brackets) and then returns how much there are of each to the user.

The problem I have is that say I put in "Hello There" it stops counting spots after the "o" in Hello. So after the first word.

Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int upper = 0;
    int lower = 0;
    int other = -1;
    int total = 0;
    String input;
    System.out.println("Enter the phrase: ");
    input = scan.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) upper++;
        if (Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(i))) lower++;
        else other++;
        total = upper + lower + other;
    }
    System.out.println("The total number of letters is " + total);
    System.out.println("The number of upper case letters is " + upper);
    System.out.println("The number of lower case letters is " + lower);
    System.out.println("The number of other letters is " + other);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern.

The problem is that `next` doesn't see the word "There" since "Hello World" is not a complete token.

Change `next` to [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--).

Advice: Use the debugger and you'll find the problem quickly, and when you have doubts refer to the docs, they're there for you.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even see that of all things.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that `next()` only returns the line before a space but `nextLine()` will read the whole line.

So Change

```
scan.next();
```

to

```
scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `next()` to `nextLine()`- it will read all the line

Answer (score 0):

As others have said. You should change from `scn.next` to `scn.nextLine()`. But why? This is because `scn.next()` only read until it encounters a space, and it stops reading. So whatever input after a space will not be read.

`scn.nextLine()` reads until a newline (i.e. `enter`) is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with regular expressions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hello There";
    int lowerCase = countMatches(Pattern.compile("[a-z]+"), input);
    int upperCase = countMatches(Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+"), input);
    int other = input.length() - lowerCase - upperCase; 
    System.out.printf("lowerCase:%s, upperCase:%s, other:%s%n", lowerCase, upperCase, other);
} 

private static int countMatches(Pattern pattern, String input) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int count = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```